# Using R to find the start difference of two strings

Tags: r, string, compare

I'm trying to use R to find the start difference of two strings, i.e. from which letter these two strings become different, and hope the function can give me the location number. The function always give the value 2, and seems the loop only runs one time.

Here is my code:

```
string1 = "CGCGGTGCATCCTGGGAGTTGTAGTTTTTTCTACTCAGAGGGAGAATAGCTCCAGACGGGAGCAGGATGA"
string2 = "CGCGGTGCATCCTGGGATGTAGTTTTTTCTACTCAGAGGGAGAATAGCTCCAGACGGGAGCAGGATGA"

location <- function(string1, string2){
  len1 = nchar(string1)
  len2 = nchar(string2)
  len = max(len1, len2)
  score = 1
  i = 1
  if (i <= len){
     if (substring(string1, i, i) == substring(string2, i, i)){
     score = score + 1
     i = i + 1
   }
  else if (substring(string1, i, i) != substring(string2, i, i)){
  break
   }
 }
  return(score)
}

location(string1, string2)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can split the string and compare character by character and get the first mismatch using `which.min`

```
which.min(strsplit(string1, "")[[1]] == strsplit(string2, "")[[1]])
#[1] 18
```

The above method returns a warning message when `nchar(string1)` is not equal to `nchar(string2)`

> Warning message:
>   In strsplit(string1, "")[[1]] == strsplit(string2, "")[[1]] :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Most of the cases it would be fine to ignore this message, it would still give you correct answer.

However, to make it complete and reliable we can write a function

```
location <- function(string1, string2) {
  n = pmin(nchar(string1), nchar(string2))
  i = 1
  while (i <= n) {
    if (substr(string1, i, i) != substr(string2, i, i)) 
       return(i)
    i = i + 1
  }
 cat("There is no difference between two strings")
}

location(string1, string2)
#[1] 18

location("Ronak", "Shah")
#[1] 1

location("Ronak", "Ronak")
#There is no difference between two strings
```

Comment: hi Ronak im exactly looking  something like this to compare nucleotide stretches  so lets say i get 20 places or strings which are different in two comparison any way to print those?

Comment: Instead of `return(i)` you can store the position where we encounter the difference. If you have difficulty implementing the solution you can ask it as a new question.

Comment: let me try first and let you know

Comment: I did ask question in this section of R forum  couple of days back i think but now i see this message no more question allowed from this account ...im not sure how do i create new question ...

Answer (score 3):

Base function `abbreviate`can give the solution, since, with its defaults, it tries to find the first char making the difference between strings in order to make unique abbreviations :

```
nchar(abbreviate(c(string1,string2),minlength=1)[1])
#CGCGGTGCATCCTGGGAGTTGTAGTTTTTTCTACTCAGAGGGAGAATAGCTCCAGACGGGAGCAGGATGA 
#                                                                    18

nchar(abbreviate(c("ABCDE","DEFGH"),minlength=1)[1])
#ABCDE 
#    1
```

Comment: That's another good way to rethink about the algorithm behind this problem. Thanks.